# Combining Forest Plots in One Plot

Tags: r, meta-analysis, forest-plot

I am trying to combine 4 forest plots into 1 matrix type plot output with 2 columns and 2 rows.

I have tried grid.arrange multiple times but I continue to get "only grobs allowed in list."

- The meta functions are done using **metacont** as my data is continuous

**My code is as follows:**

*plot_ma<-forest(ma_meta, xlab = "title")*

*plot_m1<-forest(m1_meta, xlab = "title")*

*plot_m2<-forest(m2_meta, xlab = "title")*

*plot_ab<-forest(ab_meta, xlab = "title")*

---

I would like for these to be combined in a matrix format so that my output can be one matrix of the 4 plots.

Thank you

Comment: I don't use R, but when I want to do this in other software, I set it up as subgroup analyses with no pooling across the subgroups.

Comment: Cold you post the code that you use for `grid.arrange`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(plot_ma, plot_m1, plot_m2, plot_ab, ncol=2,top="Your Title")
```

or with base graphics:

```
par(mfrow = c(4, 1))
forest(ma_meta, xlab = "title")
forest(m1_meta, xlab = "title")
forest(m2_meta, xlab = "title")
forest(ab_meta, xlab = "title")
par(mfrow = c(1, 1)) #reset this parameter
```

Comment: The first code gave me this error `Error in gList(...) : only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"`. Any advice please.